# How to put an image onclick on pin on map?

Tags: android, image, google-maps, annotations

I have made a simple map application in that I've put a mapview clickable and zoomable, I have put a static point on map with static latitude and Longitude and a pin image to point out the place, Now I want is that when I click on that pin a commentbox image should open. My code is as below:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.maps;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {
MapView mapview;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapview = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapview.setSatellite(true); 
        mapview.setTraffic(true); 

        MapController mc =mapview.getController();
        double lat = Double.parseDouble("23.0355018");
        double lon = Double.parseDouble("72.5630625");
        GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1E6),(int) (lon*1E6));
        mc.animateTo(gp);
        mc.setZoom(15);
        mapview.invalidate();
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapview.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);
       // Drawable drawable1 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yellowhite1comment);

        AddItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay =
        new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(gp, "Hello", "Sample Overlay item");

        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
}
```

**AddItemizedOverlay.java**

```
  package com.example.maps;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

import android.R.bool;
import android.R.drawable;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class AddItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Context context;
MainActivity mainact = new MainActivity();

    public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultmarker) {

        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultmarker));
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultmarker,Context context){
    this(defaultmarker);
    this.context=context;

}
    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return mapOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
       protected boolean onTap(int index) {

           OverlayItem item = mapOverlays.get(index);

           //Initialize context in the AddItemizedClass Constructor.
           item.setMarker(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yellowhite1comment));

           mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

           //itemizedOverlay is like a global object;

           itemizedOverlay.populateNow();

           return true;
       }
    public void populateNow()
    {
        populate(); 
    }
    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mapOverlays.add(overlay);
         this.populate();
     }
    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should search and try it by yourself first as you can find many posts as answer of your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add marker on touched location using google map in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171429/add-marker-on-touched-location-using-google-map-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in AddItemizedOverlay class

```
  @Override
   protected boolean onTap(int index) {

       OverlayItem item = mapOverlays.get(index);

       //Initialize context in the AddItemizedClass Constructor.
       item.setMarker(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.comment_box));

       mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

       //itemizedOverlay is like a global object;

       itemizedOverlay.populateNow();

       return true;
   }
```

Comment: @Santhosh-sir...i want an image to populate on click on my pin image on map..are you getting me?

Comment: you want the image on the pin? just say Santhosh

Comment: @santhosh-ok...sry brothr..! we'll i have put an image like a comment box in my drawable and i need is that when i click on my pin on map,the image in drwable should populate ,because i want to put details of that place in that image as text....get my problem santhosh? bro ..pls help me..

Comment: onTap use the OverlayItem and set a new Marker drawable for that. wait i will edit my answer.

Comment: @santhosh-i m not getting from where the "itemizedOverlay" object will be used and how to make it globally brothr..can you pls tell me? thanking you...hav a nyc day...bro..!

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

> ```
> public class MapendPointsOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
> private ArrayList<OverlayItem> m_overlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
> private BalloonOverlayView m_balloonView;
> private OverlayItem m_overlayitem;
> private Context m_context;
> private int m_viewOffset;
> private MapController m_mapController;
> private MapView m_mapView;
> private int m_screenWidth;
> private int m_screenHeight;
> private Display m_screen;
> private boolean m_fromroutepath = false;
> public MapendPointsOverlay(Drawable p_drawable) {
>     super(p_drawable);
> }
> public MapendPointsOverlay(Drawable p_defaultMarker, Context p_context,
>         MapView p_mapview, boolean p_fromroutepath) {
>     super(boundCenterBottom(p_defaultMarker));
>     m_context = p_context;
>     m_mapView = p_mapview;
>     m_mapController = p_mapview.getController();
>     m_viewOffset = 35;
>     m_fromroutepath = p_fromroutepath;
>     m_screen = ((WindowManager) m_context           .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
>     m_screenWidth = m_screen.getWidth();
>     m_screenHeight = m_screen.getHeight();
> }
> /**
>  * Method that creates an OverlayItem from the list of OverlayItem at index
>  * given by <b>p_arg0</b>
>  */
> @Override
> protected OverlayItem createItem(int p_arg0) {
>     return m_overlays.get(p_arg0);
> }
> @Override
> public int size() {
>     return m_overlays.size();
> }
> @Override
> protected boolean onTap(int p_index) {
>     boolean m_isRecycled;
>     GeoPoint m_point;
>     m_point = createItem(p_index).getPoint();
>     m_overlayitem = m_overlays.get(p_index);
>     if (m_balloonView == null) {
>         m_balloonView = new BalloonOverlayView(m_context, m_viewOffset);
>         m_isRecycled = false;
>     } else {
>         m_isRecycled = true;
>     }
>     m_balloonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>     m_balloonView.setData(m_overlayitem);
>     m_balloonView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>     MapView.LayoutParams m_params = new MapView.LayoutParams(
>      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, m_point,MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);
>     m_params.mode = MapView.LayoutParams.MODE_MAP;
>     List<Overlay> m_mapOverlays = m_mapView.getOverlays();
>     if (m_mapOverlays.size() > 1) {
>         hideOtherBalloons(m_mapOverlays);
>     }
>     if (m_isRecycled) {
>         m_balloonView.setLayoutParams(m_params);
>     } else {
>         m_mapView.addView(m_balloonView, m_params);
>     }
>     m_mapController.animateTo(m_point);
>     m_mapController.setCenter(m_point);
>     return true;
> }
> /**
>  * Sets the visibility of this overlay's balloon view to GONE.
>  */
> private void hideBalloon() {
>     if (m_balloonView != null) {
>         m_balloonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>     }
> }
> /**
>  * Hides the balloon view for any other BalloonItemizedOverlay instances
>  * that might be present on the MapView.
>  * 
>  * @param p_overlays
>  *            - list of overlays (including this) on the MapView.
>  */
> private void hideOtherBalloons(List<Overlay> p_overlays) {
>     for (Overlay m_overlay : p_overlays) {
>         if (m_overlay instanceof MapendPointsOverlay && m_overlay != this) {
>             ((MapendPointsOverlay) m_overlay).hideBalloon();
>         }
>     }
> }
> /**
>  * Override this method to handle a "tap" on a balloon. By default, does
>  * nothing and returns false.
>  * 
>  * @param p_index
>  *            - The index of the item whose balloon is tapped.
>  * @return true if you handled the tap, otherwise false.
>  */
> protected boolean onBalloonTap(int p_index) {
>     return false;
> }
> /**
>  * Method to filter all points based on the projection given by
>  * <b>p_projection</b>, FrameWidth <b>p_frameWidth</b>, FrameHeight
>  * <b>p_frameHeight</b>
>  * 
>  * @param p_projection
>  *            The projection of the mapview
>  * @param p_frameWidth
>  *            The width of the screen
>  * @param p_frameHeight
>  *            The height of the screen
>  */
> public void filterAllPoints(Projection p_projection, int p_frameWidth,
>         int p_frameHeight) {
>     try {
>         for (int m_i = 0; m_i < AppConstants.m_geoItems.length; m_i++) {
>             GeoItem m_tempLoc = AppConstants.m_geoItems[m_i];
>             GeoPoint m_geopoint = m_tempLoc.getLocation();
>             Point m_scPoint = new Point();
>             p_projection.toPixels(m_geopoint, m_scPoint);
>             if (m_scPoint.x > 20 && m_scPoint.y > 20
>                     && m_scPoint.x < (p_frameWidth)
>                     && m_scPoint.y < (p_frameHeight)) {
>                 OverlayItem m_overlayitem = new OverlayItem(m_geopoint, ""
>                         + m_tempLoc.m_id, "location"/*
>                                                      * Integer.toString(tempLoc
>                                                      * .getLocationId())
>                                                      */);
>                 addOverlay(m_overlayitem);
>             }
>         }
>     } catch (Exception p_e) {
>          p_e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> }
> /**
>  * 
>  * Method to filter <b>p_recordCount</b> points based on the projection
>  * given by <b>p_projection</b>, FrameWidth <b>p_frameWidth</b>, FrameHeight
>  * <b>p_frameHeight</b>
>  * 
>  * @param p_recordCount
>  *            Th number of points to be filtered
>  * @param p_projection
>  *            The projection of the mapview
>  * @param p_frameWidth
>  *            The width of the screen
>  * @param p_frameHeight
>  *            The height of the screen
>  */
> public void filterPoints(int p_recordCount, Projection p_projection,
>         int p_frameWidth, int p_frameHeight) {
>     int m_noOfRecords = 0;
>     try {
>         for (int m_i = 0; m_noOfRecords < p_recordCount
>                 && m_i <= AppConstants.m_geoItems.length - 1; m_i++) {
>             GeoItem m_tempLoc = AppConstants.m_geoItems[m_i];
>             GeoPoint m_geopoint = m_tempLoc.getLocation();
>             Point m_scPoint = new Point();
>             p_projection.toPixels(m_geopoint, m_scPoint);
>             if (m_scPoint.x > 20 && m_scPoint.y > 20
>                     && m_scPoint.x < (p_frameWidth)
>                     && m_scPoint.y < (p_frameHeight)) {
>                 OverlayItem m_overlayitem = new OverlayItem(m_geopoint, ""
>                         + m_tempLoc.m_id, "location"
>                 addOverlay(m_overlayitem);
>                 m_noOfRecords++;                }
>         }
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         // TODO: handle exception
>          e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> }
> /**
>  * Method to set the first 10 defined points in the Array of geoitems
>  * AppConstants.m_first10geoItems
>  */
> public void setFirst10Points() {
>     try {
>         for (int m_i = 0; m_i < AppConstants.m_first10geoItems.length; m_i++) {
>             GeoItem m_tempLoc = AppConstants.m_first10geoItems[m_i];
>             GeoPoint m_geopoint = m_tempLoc.getLocation();
>             OverlayItem m_overlayitem = new OverlayItem(m_geopoint, ""
>                     + m_tempLoc.m_id, "location"
>             addOverlay(m_overlayitem);
>         }
>     } catch (Exception p_e) {
>         // TODO: handle exception
>     }
> }
> /**
>  * Method to set the overlays on the Mapview given by <b>p_mapView</b>
>  * 
>  * @param p_mapView
>  *            The mapview on which the overlays are to be drawn
>  */
> public void setLocationOverlays(MapView p_mapView) {
>     clearOverlays();
>     int m_zoomLevel = p_mapView.getZoomLevel();
>     Projection m_mapViewprojection = p_mapView.getProjection();
>     try {
>         // if (!(m_zoomLevel > 16) && !(m_zoomLevel < 12))
>         if (!(m_zoomLevel < 12)) {
>             if (AppConstants.m_geoItems != null
>                     && AppConstants.m_geoItems.length > 0) {
>                 if (m_zoomLevel == 12) {
>                     if (AppConstants.m_geoItems.length == 1) {
>                         filterAllPoints(m_mapViewprojection,
>                                 (m_screenWidth - 5), (m_screenHeight - 25));
>                     } else {
>                         if (AppConstants.m_first10geoItems != null) {
>                             setFirst10Points();
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>                 else if (m_zoomLevel > 12) {
>                     // Display 10 Records
>                     filterPoints(10, m_mapViewprojection,
>                             (m_screenWidth - 5), (m_screenHeight - 25));
>                 } else {
>                     // Display all the records available in the current                     // screen
>                     filterAllPoints(m_mapViewprojection,
>                             (m_screenWidth - 5), (m_screenHeight - 25));
>                 }
>                 p_mapView.invalidate();
>             }
>         }  
>         }
>     } catch (Exception p_e) {
>     }
> }
> /**
>  * Method to set the listener for the zoom controls of mapview given by
>  * <b>p_controls</b>
>  * 
>  * @param p_controls
>  *            The Zoom controls of the mapview
>  */
> public void setZoomControlListener(ZoomControls p_controls) {
>     p_controls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             hideBalloon();
>             if (m_mapView.getZoomLevel() > 16) {
>             } else {
>                 m_mapView.getController().zoomIn();
>                 setLocationOverlays(m_mapView);
>             }
>         }
>     });
>     p_controls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             hideBalloon();
>             if (m_mapView.getZoomLevel() > 12) {
>                 m_mapView.getController().zoomOut();
>                 setLocationOverlays(m_mapView);
>             }
>         }
>     });
> }
> @Override
> public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent p_event, MapView p_mapView) {
>     if (!(p_mapView.getZoomLevel() > 16)
>             && !(p_mapView.getZoomLevel() < 12)) {
>         if (p_event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
>             hideBalloon();
>         }
>         if (p_event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
>             if (m_fromroutepath) {
>                 System.out.println("From RoutePath");
>             } else {
>                 setLocationOverlays(p_mapView);
>             }
>         }
>     } else {
>         hideBalloon();
>         if (p_mapView.getZoomLevel() > 16) {
>             p_mapView.getController().setZoom(16);
>         }
>     }
>     return super.onTouchEvent(p_event, p_mapView);
> }
> /**
>  * Method to add the overlay given by <b>p_overlay</b> on the ampview
>  * 
>  * @param p_overlay
>  *            The overlay to be added in the list of overlays on the map
>  */
> public synchronized void addOverlay(OverlayItem p_overlay) {
>     m_overlays.add(p_overlay);
>     // m_mapView.getOverlays().add(p_overlay);
>     populate();
> }
> /**
>  * Method to clear all the overlays from the mapview
>  */
> public synchronized void clearOverlays() {
>     m_overlays.clear();
>     populate();
> }}
> ```

**BallonOverlay class**

> ```
>  public class BalloonOverlayView extends FrameLayout
>   {
> private LinearLayout m_layout;
> private TextView m_title;
> private TextView m_snippet;
> /**
>  * Create a new BalloonOverlayView.
>  * 
>  * @param p_context
>  *            - The activity context.
>  * @param p_balloonBottomOffset
>  *            - The bottom padding (in pixels) to be applied when rendering this view.
>  */
> public BalloonOverlayView(Context p_context, int p_balloonBottomOffset)
> {
>     super(p_context);
>     setPadding(10, 0, 10, p_balloonBottomOffset);
>     m_layout = new LinearLayout(p_context);
>     m_layout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
>     LayoutInflater m_inflater = (LayoutInflater) p_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>     View m_view = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.balloonoverlay, m_layout);
>     m_title = (TextView) m_view.findViewById(R.id.balloon_item_title);
>     m_snippet = (TextView) m_view.findViewById(R.id.balloon_item_snippet);
>     m_snippet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>     ImageView m_close = (ImageView) m_view.findViewById(R.id.close_img_button);
>     m_close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
>         public void onClick(View v)
>         {
>             m_layout.setVisibility(GONE);
>         }
>     });     
>     FrameLayout.LayoutParams m_params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
>     m_params.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
>     addView(m_layout, m_params);
> }   
> /**
>  * Sets the view data from a given overlay item.
>  * 
>  * @param p_item
>  *            - The overlay item containing the relevant view data (title and snippet).
>  */
> public void setData(OverlayItem p_item)
> {
>     m_layout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
>     if (p_item.getTitle() != null)
>     {
>         m_title.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
>         m_title.setText(p_item.getTitle());
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         m_title.setVisibility(GONE);
>     }       
>     if (p_item.getSnippet() != null)
>     {
>         m_snippet.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
>         m_snippet.setText(p_item.getSnippet());
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         m_snippet.setVisibility(GONE);
>     }
>      }  
> /**
>  * Method to set the view data from a given geopoint
>  * 
>  * @param p_point
>  *            The geopoint
>  */
> public void setData(GeoPoint p_point)
> {
>     m_layout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
>     m_title.setText("Latitude=" + p_point.getLatitudeE6() + "\n Longitude=" + p_point.getLongitudeE6());
> }
> }
> ```

Comment: @Grishu-Dear i appreciate your help,but its too much long code..its not good to put such a large code for just a populating image..rite.Thanking you dear...hav a nyc day..

Comment: @jimmycool - I have implemented this way only.. And AFAIK in google map v1 you need to implement everything on your own for the info window. nywz thnx dear :)