# Add Marker on Android Google Map via touch or tap

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker, touch-event

I want to develop a Map Application using Google Map on Android.
Now, I want to add marker on the map via Touch or Tap on the Map. How do I apply touch event to drop the marker on the map?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add marker on touched location using google map in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171429/add-marker-on-touched-location-using-google-map-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is Successful run I am working on that code this code is for *Dynamic Draw*

I think this code help you more for Static or dynamic both places you can use 
  this code

```
double latval = Double.parseDouble(jsonobject.getString("lat"));
double longval = Double.parseDouble(jsonobject.getString("lon"));

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
               .position(new LatLng( latval,    longval))
               .title(jsonobject.getString("country"))
               .snippet("4 E. 28TH Street From $15 /per night")
               .rotation((float) -15.0)
               .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE))
              );

if (i == 0) {
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                new LatLng(latval, longval), 7));
    mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                   .center(new LatLng(latval,longval))
                   .radius(5000)
                   .strokeColor(Color.RED)
                   .fillColor(Color.RED)); 
}
```

Comment: @shiteru This should not be the accepted answer. It does not answer the original question, but this answer does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17147121/2102748. It may have helped you solve the problem, but it does not contain the answer to the question and is misleading for new visitors.

Comment: how is this the accepted answer? it does not answer the question at all.

Answer (score 82):

Try using new [Google Map API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start).

It's easy to use and you can add a marker on tap like this:

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        allPoints.add(point);
        map.clear();
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point));
    }
});
```

or in **Kotlin**:

```
map.setOnMapClickListener {
    allPoints.add(it)
    map.clear()
    map.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(it))
}
```

Note that you might want to remember all your added points in a list (`allPoints`), so you can re-draw or remove them later. An even better approach to remember the points would be to remember a `Marker` object for each of them - you can get the `Marker` object as a result from the `addMarker` function, it has a `remove()` function that easily removes the marker from the map.

Comment: in here what is  lstLatLngs.add(point);  ?

i mean lstLatLngs which ones object you dont clerify ?

Answer (score 20):

The technique which i used is:

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {           
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude)).title("New Marker");
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        System.out.println(point.latitude+"---"+ point.longitude);  
    }
});
```

Hope it helps!!!