# How to drop marker on map and translate position to lat and long coordinates?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, latitude-longitude, google-maps-api-2

I'm using Google maps API v2 and I'm trying to figure out how I would allow a marker to be dropped on a SupportMapFragment and set the marked position to lattitude and longtitude variables.I have figured out how to get the path from two hard coded points but not this way.

I have come across this solution which is useful for adding markers [How to show multiple markers on MapFragment in Google Map API v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855049/how-to-show-multiple-markers-on-mapfragment-in-google-map-api-v2) but not applicable for dropping a marker on the map fragment and translating the coordinates.

Does anyone have any pointers on doing this or where I would start with this implementation?

This is how the interface looks at present:

[image]

Comment: Just for fun I made a quick demo of the marker add and drag and put it in the play store.  [app in playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gosylvester.demomapmarkeraddanddrag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean, by drop a marker, to add a marker to the map by the users touch, you will find the answer here.

[Add Marker on Android Google Map via touch or tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143129/add-marker-on-android-google-map-via-touch-or-tab)