# How to add markers to map by touching in MapQuest?

Tags: android, mapquest

Now I can show the map and markers that are defined in the program, but I need to add markers to touched location.

I think I know the way to do this, which is:

1 To set something like onTouchEventListener to the MapView;

2 Get the position information from Listener;

3 Set the marker according to the position information.

But I am too new to this to find out how to write code to achieve it, especially the step 1. I mean I don't understand how to use the solution like [Add marker on touched location using google map in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171429/add-marker-on-touched-location-using-google-map-in-android) .My problem is more fundamental. I dont know how to set eventListener for my MapView and which eventListener should I use. https://developer.mapquest.com/content/mobile/android/documentation/api/com/mapquest/android/maps/Overlay.OverlayTouchEventListener.html This OverlayTouchEventListener seems to be the one but cant find an useful guide for it.

So could some one tell me how to do this in detail?
Eg.How to set the listener and which listener to choose?

Comment: How are you using MapQuest?  Is this a native Android app, or a web app?

Comment: It is a map API that provides with a MapView. I use it as a MapView like GoogleMap's MapView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

**1. Create interface MyGeoPointListener.java**

```
  public interface MyGeoPointListener {
    public void GetGeoPoint(GeoPoint geopoint);
  }
```

**2. Create Overlay class:**

```
import com.mapquest.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.mapquest.android.maps.OverlayItem;
class DynamicMarkerOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private boolean isPinch = false;
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private MyGeoPointListener geoPointListener;

    public DynamicMarkerOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker,
            MyGeoPointListener geoPointListener) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        this.geoPointListener = geoPointListener;
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint geoPoint, MapView map) {

        if (isPinch) {
            return false;
        } else {

            if (geoPoint != null) {
                if (null != geoPointListener) {
                    geoPointListener.GetGeoPoint(geoPoint);
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                if (null != geoPointListener) {
                    geoPointListener.GetGeoPoint(null);
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {
        int fingers = event.getPointerCount();
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            isPinch = false; // Touch DOWN, don't know if it's a pinch yet
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && fingers == 2) {
            isPinch = true; // Two fingers, def a pinch
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event, mapView);
    }

}
```

**3. Implement MyGeoPointListener in activity**

like,

`public class MainActivity extends MapActivity implements MyGeoPointListener {`

**4. Override MyGeoPointListener:**

```
.....

@Override
public void GetGeoPoint(GeoPoint geopoint) {
    if (null != geopoint) {
        String msg = "Lat: " + geopoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + " - "
                + "Lon: " + geopoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MyLocationMap.this, msg,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = myMap.getOverlays();
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geopoint, "address_name",
                "address");
        Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.location_marker);
        DynamicMarkerOverlay customoverlay = new DynamicMarkerOverlay(icon,
                this);
        customoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(customoverlay);
        myMap.getController().animateTo(geopoint);
    }
 }

 .....
```

**5. In OnCreate()**

```
......
public MapView myMap;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_map_layout);

    .......
    .......

    myMap = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

    Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    marker.setBounds(0, 0, marker.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            marker.getIntrinsicHeight());

    myMap.getOverlays().add(new DynamicMarkerOverlay(marker, this));
   
   ......
}
```

**6. Result:**

[image: Add markers to map by touching in MapQuest]

Comment: Thank you. However, my problem is a more fundamental problem, which is I dont know how to set eventListener for the my MapView. I dont know how to integrate your code into my code...